# Is there any good books about SSCLI?

Tags: .net, clr, sscli

More and more I realized that without jumping into the code details, I cannot really understand the how CLR works.

So could you recommend some good books on SSCLI (Shared Source CLI)?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [Shared Source CLI Essentials](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059600351X).

For detailed information on the CLR, Jeffrey Ricther's [CLR via C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735627045) is really useful. Make sure to get the recently published 3rd edition as it has updated info on CLR 4.

Also, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477748/what-are-the-best-c-net-books/477751#477751).

Comment: the appended question leads me to the book by Jon Skeet, great thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following post on Joel Pobar's blog has a link to download [the latest version of the SSCLI 2.0 book](http://callvirt.net/blog/post/SSCLI-20-Patch-for-VS-2010.aspx).  It also contains a link to a patch that you can overlay on the distribution to allow it to be built in Visual Studio 2010.